# Django no reverse match error while using url dispatcher

Tags: python, html, django

I have an app that runs some long running tasks and I am showing the log of runs (a table) that a user has made on a particular page. There is a result location in the table on the page, where I would like for it to be a hyperlink and when clicked, gets redirected to a page where the user can see the result.

I am getting a :

`NoReverseMatch: Reverse for 'past_run_results' with arguments '(u'1649103c-67d0-47f9-a085-401c02acff6a',)' not found. 1 pattern(s) tried: ['discovery-engine/past-runs/(P<task_id>[-\\w]+)$']`

and I can't figure out what is wrong

/urls.py

```
[
url(r'^past-runs/$', views.past_run_log, name="previous_runs"),
url(r'^past-runs/(P<task_id>[-\w]+)$', views.past_run_results, name="past_run_results"),
]
```

/views.py

```
def past_run_log(request):
    past_fifty_runs = JobLog.objects.all().filter(user=request.user)[:50]
    context_dict = {"past_runs": past_fifty_runs}
    return render(request, 'website/previous_runs.html', context=context_dict)


def past_run_results(request, task_id):
    get_result = JobLog.objects.get(task_id=task_id)
    read_location = os.path.join(os.getcwd(), "results", get_result.result_location)
    with open(read_location) as f:
       result_data = json.load(f)

    if result_data:
        return render(request, 'website/previous_runs_results.html', context={"result": result_data})
    else:
        return render(request, 'website/previous_runs_results.html', context={"result": "No result found."})
```

/previous_runs.html

```
<div class="container-fluid">
    <div class="row">
        <div class="col-xs-12">
            <h1>History</h1>

            <table data-toggle="table" data-search="true" data-pagination="true" class="table-responsive">
                <thead>
                    <tr>
                        <th>Task Name</th>
                        <th>Username</th>
                        <th>Algortihm Name</th>
                        <th>Start Time</th>
                        <th>Duration (secs)</th>
                        <th>Status</th>
                        <th>Result</th>
                    </tr>
                </thead>
                <tbody>
                    {% for run in past_runs %}
                        <tr>
                            <td>{{run.task_name}}</td>
                            <td>{{run.user}}</td>
                            <td>{{run.algorithm}}</td>
                            <td>{{run.time_started}}</td>
                            <td>{{run.time_taken | floatformat:2}}</td>
                            <td>{{run.status}}</td>
                            <td><a href="{% url 'past_run_results' run.task_id %}">{{run.result_location}}</a></td>
                        </tr>
                    {% endfor %}
                </tbody>
            </table>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

The task_id is a unique key such as `1649103c-67d0-47f9-a085-401c02acff6a`.
Django version is `1.11` and python version `2.7`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are missing the question mark in `(?P<task_id>[-\w]+)`.